# How to properly capture library / package version in my package when using pyproject.toml to build

Tags: python, metadata, python-packaging

I have moved away from a `setup.py` file to build my packages / libraries to fully using `pyproject.toml`.  I prefer it overall, but it seems that the version placed in the `pyproject.toml` does not propagate through the build in any way. So I cannot figure out how to inject the package version -- or any other metadata provided in the pyproject.toml -- into my package.

A google search led me to [this thread](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/273), which had some suggestions. They all seemed like hacks, but I tried this one because it seemed best:

```py
from pip._vendor import tomli ## I need to be backwards compatible to Python 3.8

with open("pyproject.toml", "rb") as proj_file:
    _METADATA = tomli.load(proj_file)

DESCRIPTION = _METADATA["project"]["description"]
NAME = _METADATA["project"]["name"]
VERSION = _METADATA["project"]["version"]
```

It worked fine upon testing, but I did not test robustly enough: once I tried to install this in a fresh location / machine, it failed because the `pyproject.toml` file is not part of the package installation. (I should have realized this.)

---

So, what is the right / best way to provide metadata, like the package version, to my built package?  I need the following requirements:

1. I *only* want to provide the information once, in the `pyproject.toml`. (I know that if I need to repeat a value, at some point there will be a mismatch.)
2. I want the information to be available to the end user, so that someone who installs the package can do something like `mypackage.VERSION` from her interactive Python session.
3. I want to *only* use `pyproject.toml` and Poetry / PDM.  (I actually use PDM, but I know that Poetry is more popular. The point is that I don't want a `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` hack. I want to purely use the new way.)

Comment: And why not avoid writing version anywhere in your package, indeed? Replace your `VERSION` with `get_version()` function, that will return `importlib.metadata.version('MyPackage')`. Finally, you can define module-level `__getattr__`, if you really need this to be a VERSION constant-like property. This solves all three points.

Comment: `get_version()` will have the same problems as what I wrote above:  the problem is that the `pyproject.toml` will not be part of the installed package.

Comment: `importlib.metadata.version` does not read pyproject.toml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, the `pyproject.toml` file from the original [source tree](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#source-trees) is generally not available to read from within an installed package. This isn't new, it's also the case that the `setup.py` file from a legacy source tree would be missing from an actual installation. The package metadata, however, is available in a [.dist-info subdirectory](https://peps.python.org/pep-0376/#one-dist-info-directory-per-installed-distribution) alongside your package installation.

To demonstrate using a real example of an installed package and the corresponding metadata files, which contain the version info and other stuff coming from the `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`:

```
$ pip install -q six
$ pip show --files six
Name: six
Version: 1.16.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: https://github.com/benjaminp/six
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /tmp/eg/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
Files:
  __pycache__/six.cpython-311.pyc
  six-1.16.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
  six-1.16.0.dist-info/LICENSE
  six-1.16.0.dist-info/METADATA
  six-1.16.0.dist-info/RECORD
  six-1.16.0.dist-info/REQUESTED
  six-1.16.0.dist-info/WHEEL
  six-1.16.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
  six.py
$ grep '^Version:' .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/six-1.16.0.dist-info/METADATA
Version: 1.16.0
```

This `.dist-info/METADATA` file is the location containing the version info and other metadata. Users of your package, and the package itself, may access package metadata if/when necessary by using stdlib [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html). The [version string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions) is guaranteed to be there for an installed package, because it's a [required field](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#core-metadata-specifications) in the metadata specification, and there is a dedicated function for it. Other keys, which are optional, can be found using the [metadata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-metadata) headers, e.g.:

```
>>> from importlib.metadata import metadata
>>> metadata("six")["Summary"]
'Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities'
```

All versions of Python where accessing the metadata was non-trivial are now EOL, but if you need to maintain support for Python <= 3.7 then [importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) from PyPI can be used the same way as stdlib.

When you only publish one top-level directory containing an `__init__.py` file and it has the same name as the project name in `pyproject.toml`, then you may use the `__package__` attribute so that you don't have to hardcode the package name in source code:

```
# can be accessed anywhere within the package
import importlib.metadata

the_version_str = importlib.metadata.version(__package__)
```

If the names are mismatching (example: the [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) "[python-dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/296d419fe6bf3b22897f8f210735ac9c4e1cb796/setup.cfg#L5)" provides [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) "[dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/2.8.2/dateutil/__init__.py)"), or you have multiple top-level names (example: the distribution package "[setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/80e60c3bdd5aa57f32560e5b0d946d0c07c71ac2/setup.cfg#L2)" provides import packages "[setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v68.0.0/setuptools/__init__.py)" and "[pkg_resources](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v68.0.0/pkg_resources/__init__.py)") then you may want to just hardcode the package name, or try and discover it from the installed [`packages_distributions()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#mapping-import-to-distribution-packages) mapping.

This satisfies point 1. and point 3.

For point 2.:

> I want the information to be available to the end user, so that someone who installs the package can do something like `mypackage.VERSION` from her interactive Python session.

The similar recipe works:

```
# in your_package/__init__.py
import importlib.metadata

VERSION = importlib.metadata.version(__package__)
```

However, I would recommend *not* to provide a version attribute at all. There are several disadvantages to doing that, for reasons I've described [here](https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/pull/1276#issuecomment-1646696925) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167802/adding-version-attribute-to-python-module/72168209#72168209). If you have historically provided a version attribute, and need to keep it for backwards compatibility concerns, you may consider maintaining support using a fallback module `__getattr__` which will be invoked when an attribute is not found by the usual means:

```
def __getattr__(name):
    if name == "VERSION":
        # consider adding a deprecation warning here advising caller to use
        # importlib.metadata.version directly
        return importlib.metadata.version("mypackage")
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")
```

Comment: I would warn against relying on the expectation that `__package__` is the same as the name of the distribution project. `importlib.metadata.version()` expects the name of the distribution package (the name of the project), not the name of an import package.

Comment: @sinoroc Quite right. It's my recommendation that users ought to publish one top-level package name which is matching the project name, to make everybody's life easier, but I've edited the answer to point out that this is not guaranteed to be matching in the general case.

Comment: Thank you greatly, @wim !  Not only did I learn a lot about `importlib.metadata` and `pip show --files`, but you also convinced me that putting `VERSION` in the package itself is not good.  I still find it useful for newbies, because this is the sort of thing most other languages trivially allow.  But as you point out, there are too many disadvantages for this to be a sufficient reason to add it.  I have therefore removed any efforts to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to put inside the package **init**.py file:

```
import importlib.metadata
try:
    VERSION = importlib.metadata.version(__package__ or __name__)
    __version__ = VERSION
except importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError:
    pass
```

**version** / VERSION attrbutes will be available for installed packages. Locally during package dev with pyproject.toml these attributes will not be available, but as devs we are aware what we are doing ... :)